# Is there a way to convert incoming email to a HTTP POST request?

Tags: http, email

I'm looking for a simple service/software that will convert emails into HTTP POST requests so I don't have to code in separate code paths for email handling. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: On what platform / environment?

Comment: Linux ideally but it really doesn't matter since the ideal case would be to decouple mail handling from my web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit late but I was looking for something similar and came across http://www.email2http.net - they allow you to send your email to a web script via HTTP POST or GET and it includes attachments. If you only need 1 email address and script it's free.

Answer (score 4):

Google app engine converts incoming email into a POST to your app:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail.html

You could either handle the emails directly on app engine, or write a handler which calls back to your other site:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html

Comment: I needed to do something similar, and based on the doc wrote this simple appengine app which handles a single attachment and a few fields: https://github.com/jsvaughan/emailtohttppost

Answer (score 2):

You could run Postfix or another mail server, configure it to accept the appropriate email, and then pipe the mail to a command which POSTs the data (using CURL or another framework).

Speaking SMTP correctly as a server isn't trivial.  Access control is even harder.  I'd say to use a real SMTP server.

Comment: I could, I was just wondering if someone's already coded it up so I wouldn't have to. As for access control, what are the various ways it could break?

Comment: @Shalmanese: you could end up vulnerable to a buffer overrun, you could end up relaying mail to unintended recipients, you could lack support for SASL authentication...  The point is just that an SMTP server is already a very powerful piece of software.  It would take a long time to rewrite all the functionality there.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple services you might be interested in:
http://mailhooks.com is a good free solution for this, but there may be a delay in the time to post, and I don't believe they include attachments.

You might also look at http://mailnuggets.com which is a paid service, but posts are quicker and it includes attachments.

Answer (score 2):

I have needed to do this several times and always rolled my own Postfix solution. I finally made a docker container and open sourced it https://github.com/thingless/mailglove.